# Rails Added column to a scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, devise

I successfully added a column "name" to "posts", When I check the post in the rails console it says name is nil even after I added a post to the form.html, this is the form file.

```
<%= form_with(model: post, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post 
from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :description %>
    <%= form.text_field :description, id: :post_description %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :Name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, id: :post_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Make sure that you allow `name` in strong params. Check your controller.

Comment: There are few thing you have to check. First which version of rails you are using. Make sure you have added new filed in params.require in controller if you are using rails version 4+.

Comment: That is done at the bottom of the post controllers where it says post_params, correct. SOrry if that is  astup[id question I began rails a few days ago

Comment: THanks, its working in the rails console but when I try to add it into the index.html so I can view it nothing happens,I just add  " <td><%= post.name %></td>" this to the index.html correct?

Comment: @Pagaley12 Make sure you have created a obj in index method and with same obj you are trying to access `:name` then it should be working.

Comment: Where is the index method? is that in the posts controller?

Comment: @Pagaley12 Yes you can find index method in posts controller.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added that attribute in your permitted param list in your controller.